# Balancing Groups in .Net Regex not nesting correctly

Tags: .net, regex, balancing-groups

I am trying to wrap my head around a bug I am finding with the .Net balancing groups regex.

I am trying to match `!{}` as an opening/closing combination.

Current Regex -> `!{[^!{}]*(((?<Open>!{)[^!{}]*)+((?<Close-Open>})[^!{}]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))}`

this matches `!{some random stuff here}` successfully. It also matches `!{some other Stuff !{} with nesting}`

However, it DOES NOT match this `!{some stuff with {} just curly braces}` at all. It seems the '{}' inside the string is causing some issues as it seems to think that the group is no longer "balanced"

I am testing all of this on http://regexstorm.net/tester which is a great place for .Net specific regex testing.

To be fair I am no regex expert, and have unashamedly copied / manipulated the regex from this site http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html

I don't need it to be able to match nesting as I will use c# to traverse recursively into the matches, but i just need to be able to get a positive match on the example that is failing above.

**UPDATE**

Here is what the initial goal of the pattern is. Much like with Razor pages where it matches @{ some C# code here }  as code blocks, I have used a pattern of !{some code here} to demarcate sections of code inside a html page. I have written a website for a client where they use those "replacers" to execute custom logic inside their html pages. so for example :

```
<p> Hello !{CurrentSession.GetUser().FirstName}</p>
```

When the page is rendered out I use Regex to identify those "replacers" and then use Springframework.Net to execute that code against a known context.

This has all worked brilliantly since 2009 ( yes over 10 years ago ! ) but now they are starting to use a lot more Json type data and that is where I discovered this bug / issue with my regex.

So Imagine this example

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var myArray = [ !{CurrentSession.GetUser().GetDataOrDefault( '{Name:"MyName"}' )} ];

</script>
```

As you can see with the above example, there is Json with curly braces '{}' inside the replacer I'm trying to match !{} and that is where the regex is failing.

PS the '!' is NOT optional it MUST open with '!{' and close with '}'

thanks in advance

Comment: Does it mean there can be no `!` inside nested `{...}`? If it does not matter, you may just use `!{(?>[^{}]+|(?<Open>{)|(?<Close-Open>}))*(?(Open)(?!))}` or even `!{(?>[^{}]+|(?<Open>{)|(?<Close-Open>}))*}`

Comment: What is the meaning of curly braces without an exclamation mark? Should they still be balanced? If they should, and `!` is optional, Wiktor's solution should work for you. In such cases, one option is to introduce an escape character, for example `!{a b \{ c !{ d }  }`.

Comment: It looks like you need a dedicated code parser for that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct. I think I can use it to work through what I need, so let me give you some points as a thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
!{(?>[^{}]+|(?<Open>{)|(?<Close-Open>}))*}
```

The regex will find an exclamation mark, and then a `{` followed with any amount of paired nested curly braces up to the matching close brace.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=!%7B%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3COpen%3E%7B%29%7C%28%3F%3CClose-Open%3E%7D%29%29*%7D&i=this%20matches%20!%7Bsome%20random%20stuff%20here%7D%20successfully.%20It%20also%20matches%20!%7Bsome%20other%20Stuff%20!%7B%7D%20with%20nesting%7D).

**Details**

- `!{` - a `!{` substring
- `(?>[^{}]+|(?<Open>{)|(?<Close-Open>}))*` - zero or more repetitions (allowing no backtracking into the alternation atomic group) of

  - `[^{}]+|` - 1+ chars other than `{` and `}`, or
  - `(?<Open>{)|` - a `{` char pushed on to Group "Open" stack
  - `(?<Close-Open>})` - a  `}` char popped from Group "Open" stack saving the substring matched in Group "Close"
- `}` - a `}` char.